# how to export data to unix system location using python

Tags: python, unix

I am trying to write the file to my company's project folder which is unix system and the location is /department/projects/data/. So I used the following code

df.to_csv("/department/projects/data/Test.txt", sep='\t', header = 0)

The error message shows it cannot find the locations. how to specify the file location in Unix using python?

Comment: check that that location exists

Comment: Log into the linux machine, and cd to the folder `/department/projects/data`. If you can, you might not have permission to write to that directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the solution. It might because I am using Spyder from anaconda. As long as I use "\" instead of "\", python can recognize the location.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.to_csv("C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Test.txt", sep='\t', header = 0)
```

Either you really mean that the backslashes are doubled as in

```
df.to_csv("C:\\Users\\abc....
```

or your strings are just wrong. I believe that Python will support Unix style paths on both Windows and Unix - use that style.

Replace your \ characters with / and dump the "C:".